# EF : MVC : ASP: TPH Error - Store update, insert, or delete ... number of rows (0). Entities ... modified or deleted ... Refresh ObjectStateManager

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, table-per-hierarchy

**Error Message: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."**

Hello All,

I've created a Code First TPH(Table Per Hierarchy) within MVC and EF with a SQL compact db.

Here's the Class diagram/Hierarchy:

[Class Diagram](http://postimage.org/image/b653qe2s/)

Client and SalesRep both inherit the BaseUser class. The Key is "UserID" and it's coded with the Data Annotation `[Key]`(I'm aware that 'ID' should set it as well)

Here's where I'm at: I can seed the database with a few entries. When I try to set the "UserID" in the seeding method it seems to ignore it and just apply the UserID in numerical order...(Seems ok to me?)

furthermore here's my DbContext

```
public class SiteDB:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BaseUser> AllUsers { get; set; }//enable TPH
    public DbSet<SalesRep> SalesReps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

Next,

I have created a controller for Clients -> ClientsController with strongly typed Razor Views. With this. I now have a CRUD for the Clients. I can create new Clients without any issue, but when I try to edit a Client entry, I get the error message stated above.

I did notice something interesting I stepped through the code and the error is happening on the db.SaveChanges();

When the client is passed back into the ActionResult Edit method the UserID=0! Bizarre? I'm not sure if this is a bug or if it's an actual issue that's causing this.

[UserID=0](http://postimage.org/image/6k5zdylg/)

Your help with this is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To modify an entity you need to get it from the database: when you pass back the modified values in the Edit action you need to retrive the entity from the `db` object, getting it by ID, apply the modified values and save it.

Here an example:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, MyModel model){
 using (SiteDBdb = new SiteDB()){
  Client cl = (from c in db.Clients where c.id == id select c).First();
  cl.MyProp = model.MyProp;
  ...
  db.SaveChanges();
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: I believe I am doing that. Can you show me a small code example?

Comment: How do you handle multiple properties that have been edited? I can also do: _Client eclient = db.Clients.Find(id);_

Comment: yes you can use any query to extract your entity, you can receive all properties in the model object (or use AutoMapper)